# Is extract number with following text possible s

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

Need to extract number with 4 letters after from a string using sql teradata for example :

Col1
‘Ff10- 100 Mbps bhd’
‘Jigd 300 Gbps’
‘Gyfv 10 Mbps hhftf’
‘Htfyy hhftf’

Should be resulting
Output
100 Mbps
300 Gbps
10 Mbps
0 or same return back

Thank you

Comment: `RegExp_SubStr(Col1, '\d{1,4} ?(M|G)bps')`, or `RegExp_SubStr(Col1, '\d{1,4} ?(M|G)bps',1,1,'i')` case insensitive. Optionally a Coalesce to get the '0'